# How to group five different images in latex such that empty space among them should be minimum and values in image clear to see?

Tags: graphics, crop-image, figure-placement

[image: 5 images grouped]

I wanted to create above image in latex (Currently done using PPT). Five different images I wanted to plot as one along with there title at bottom of each figure and The visibility of values in image should be clear. Also the empty space between the figures should appropriate as shown below (it should be minimum). Currently I am putting all five figures in ppt slide, naming it and group to form one figure and the adding to latex document. But Space to namng is little and visibility is not clear.
I would be very thankful if you could suggest the way to do above thing.
Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) I suggest you take a look at [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_3)%3A_Figures%2C_Subfigures_and_Tables) presenting how to display multiple figures. In any case, for more help, you should post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) presenting what you have already tried and displaying the abstract problem you are struggling with.

Comment: Take a look at tikz and how to display data there. You‘ll find it on ctan.org . Also use the search field and the tags on this site.

Comment: Sure , I will go through resource you have provided and follow your suggetions.

Comment: You mention PPT so I am assuming it is PowerPoint. Are you trying to re-create something in LaTeX? Is is going to be a presentation or regular document? As to numbers, you would probably need to recreate figures with larger font in axes.

Comment: Yes PPT is PowerPoint. Yes , I should recreate figures with increased font size. I am doing this to include figure in my Latex document which is my assignment.  Thanks for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a regular document in LaTeX, here's an example with [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) based on what's I found in documentation. I added an outer `minipage` so you can control width of the whole block

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
Here's the page with figures ...

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \captionsetup[sub]{
        position=bottom,
        skip=2pt,
        belowskip=6pt,
    }
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{.46\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image}
            \caption{First fig}\label{fig:1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.46\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-a}
            \caption{Second fig}\label{fig:2}
        \end{subfigure}
    
        \begin{subfigure}{.46\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-b}
            \caption{Third fig}\label{fig:3}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{.46\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-c}
            \caption{Fourth fig}\label{fig:4}
        \end{subfigure}
    
        \begin{subfigure}{.46\textwidth}
            \includegraphics{example-image-plain}
            \caption{Fifth fig}\label{fig:5}
        \end{subfigure}

        \caption{Subfigures}\label{fig:subfigs}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

Some other text after the figures.
\end{document}
```

[image]